# How can I show that this set is not dense in $S^1\times S^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, dynamical-systems, rotations, dense-subspaces

> Let me define by $R_\alpha: S^1\rightarrow S^1$ to be the rotation on the circle by the angle $\alpha$. Now consider $\alpha, \beta$ and $R_\alpha, R_\beta$ and define $$M:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^1\times S^1;~~(x,y)\mapsto (R_\alpha x, R_\beta y)$$
> Assume that $\alpha=2\beta$ I need to show that $O:=\{M^n(x,y):n\geq 0\}$ is not dense in $S^1\times S^1$.

I first remark that $$M^n(x,y)=(R_\alpha^n x, R_\beta^n y)=(R_{2\beta}^n x, R_\beta^n y)=(R_\alpha^{2n} x, R_\beta^n y)$$hence $$O=\{(R_\alpha^{2n} x, R_\beta^n y):n\geq 0\}$$Now I know that I need to find a point $(u,v)\in S^1\times S^1$ such that there exists no sequence $(R_\alpha^{2n_i} u, R_\beta^{n_i} v)\rightarrow (u,v)$, but I don't see how to find such a $(u,v)$ can someone give me a hint?

Comment: @LutzLehmann sorry my mistake, it should be $M$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Can you maybe give me a hint=

Comment: I don't know, not mine. // You go back from $R^n_\alpha=R^n_{2\beta}$ to $R^{2n}_\alpha$. // If you unwind the circles, the orbit is on a line with rational slope. Back on the circles, that line closes to a circle on the torus.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry I don't get what you mean by // You go back from...//

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a:=e^{i\alpha}$ and $b:=e^{i\beta}$. $$M(x,y)=(ax,by)=(b^2x,by)$$So: $$M^n(x,y)=(b^{2n}x,b^ny)$$

Let's say we have an arbitrary pair $(x,y)$. We want to show that the set: $$\{(b^{2n}x,b^ny):n\in\Bbb N\}$$Is not dense in the torus.

Because multiplication is a homeomorphism, I just want to show that $\{(b^{2n},b^n\gamma)\}$ is not dense where $\gamma:=yx^{-1}$. I advise you to consider $(u,v)=(1,i\gamma)$.

Comment: Why don't you have $(b^{2n}x, b^nx)$?

Comment: @user123234 Please elaborate on the question. Where and why *should* I have it?

Comment: In the "definition" of $M^n(x,y)$ in your fourth line

Comment: @user123234 Oh that’s just a typo

Comment: Okey thanks! Can you maybe also tell me what was your thinking process to find the possible candidate $(u,v)$ because I would have taken something with $k$ in the first coordinate where $k$ is a fixed natural number but the second coordinate was the problem

Comment: The idea was to force the second coordinate close to something I know, then observe that the first coordinate is ’like’ the square of the second. I can choose any number $u$ not equal to the square, then it cannot converge. Originally I chose things like $(1,1)$ but that doesn’t really work because $b=1$ is possible. However $(1,i)$ is nice because $i^2\neq1$. So to make $b^n$ close to $i$ I need to make $b^n\gamma$ close to $v:=i\gamma$. As is often the case, it’s better to work it out for the simpler case $\gamma=1$ and then generalise

Comment: Perfect thanks!